# Anti-correlations in the EPR experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I'm trying to understand the section "EPR and the Bell inequality" from the book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielson and Chuang. While going through the [box](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&lpg=PA111&ots=NH2FisrBWu&dq=%22Anti-correlations%20in%20the%20EPR%20experiment%22&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false) titled "Anti-correlations in the EPR experiment," I have trouble understanding the following line:

> It turns out that no matter what choice of $v$ we make, the results of the two measurements are always opposite to one another. That is, if the measurement on the first qubit yields $+1$, then the measurement on the second qubit will yield $−1$, and vice versa.

While the authors go on explaining why this is true, I doesn't quite fit with my understanding by performing computations.

Specifically, as the authors show, first we show that $$\frac{|01\rangle-|10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{|ab\rangle-|ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},$$ up to an unobservable global phase factor, where $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are the eigenstates of $v.\sigma$. Now, the text says

> ...if a measurement of $v.\sigma$ is performed on both qubits, then we can see that a result of $+1$ ($−1$) on the first qubit implies a result of $−1$ ($+1$) on the second qubit.

That means, if we apply $v.\sigma\otimes v.\sigma$ on the state we get $$(v.\sigma\otimes v.\sigma)\frac{|ab\rangle-|ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = -\frac{|ab\rangle-|ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ How does this justify the above statement?

Also, on the same page of the book, it's mentioned that

> Alice performs a measurement of spin along the $v$ axis, that is, she measures the observable $v.\sigma$.

Shouldn't then we be using the operator $v.\sigma\otimes I$ instead of $v.\sigma \otimes v.\sigma$?

May be I'm misunderstanding something. Please help me sort this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To measure the a single-qubit observable, you rotate the qubit to align that observable's axis with the computational basis (e.g. align it along the Z axis) then do a measurement. In other words, for any single-qubit observable $O$ you measure $M_O$ by instead performing a single-qubit operation $u$ then a Z-basis measurement $M_Z$. For all $M_O$, there exists a $u$ such that $M_Z \cdot u \equiv M_O$.

Now consider the case where two parties are measuring $M_O$ on their respective parts of a singlet state. They perform $M_O$ by applying $u$ and then measuring $M_Z$. However, the singlet state is not changed by both parties applying $u$, i.e. $(u \otimes u) \cdot (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$ gives $|01\rangle - |10\rangle$ again (up to global phase). Therefore you can just drop those operations without changing the expected outcome:

$$\begin{align}
(M_O \otimes M_O) \cdot (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)
&=
(M_Z \cdot u) \otimes (M_Z \cdot u) \cdot (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)
\\
&=
(M_Z \otimes M_Z) \cdot (u \otimes u) \cdot (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)
\\
&\propto
(M_Z \otimes M_Z) \cdot (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)
\\
&\rightarrow
\text{measurements give opposite answers}
\end{align}$$

Because the singlet state gives opposite answers in the computation basis, and the singlet state is not affected by doing a basis change to both qubits, it must give opposite answers in every basis.

Answer (score 0):

I found that section very difficult to follow myself and their claims are not at all obvious. The way I understand it is as follows. We start with

\begin{equation}
\psi = \frac{|01> - |10>}{\sqrt 2}
\end{equation}

which actually is a shorthand for following probability amplitude vector:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now as an exercise it can be verified that there is no way above vector can be written as a tensor product of two unit vectors $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}$. This shows the two qubits are entangled.

The purpose and objective of the subsequent discussion seems to be to show that no matter what unitary transformation one applies to $\psi$ it is impossible to un-entangle the two qubits. So ideally this claim should be proved in context of a general unitary matrix $U$.
But the section asks us to consider measuring the observable $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\sigma}$ on each qubit. What does this statement even mean?

First, we have to construct the unitary matrix corresponding to the transformation. We start with:

\begin{equation}
\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\sigma} = v_1 X + v_2 Y + v_3 Z = \begin{pmatrix} v_3 && v_1 - iv_2 \\
v_1 + iv_2 && -v_3 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $X, Y, Z$ are the Pauli matrices.

Next "to measure the observable $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\sigma}$ on each qubit" we need to apply following matrix:

\begin{equation}
M = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\sigma} \otimes \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\sigma} =
\begin{pmatrix}
v_3^2 && v_3(v_1-iv_2) && v_3(v_1-iv_2) && (v_1-iv_2)^2 \\
v_3(v_1+iv_2) && -v_3^2 && v_1^2 - i^2v_2^2 && -v_3(v_1-iv_2) \\
v_3(v_1+iv_2) && v_1^2 - i^2v_2^2 && -v_3^2 && -v_3(v_1-iv_2) \\
(v_1+iv_2)^2 && -v_3(v_1+iv_2) && -v_3(v_1+iv_2) && v_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

No guarantee above is correct but if it is, it turns out that:

\begin{equation}
M \psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

irrespective of what $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are (of course $v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2 = 1$).
Again this (the RHS) cannot be factored out into a tensor product of two 2x1 vectors and this tells me that the qubits cannot be un-entangled. If the qubit register is measured it will be 01 or 10. A result of +1(-1) on the first qubit implies a result of -1(+1) on the second qubit.